# How do I use Unity DI to load an assembly with dependencies and then register the internals

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container, entity-framework-5

I've got a asp.net mvc 3 web application that has plugin assemblies that implement system dependent EFcontexts and services.

For example,  I've got an assembly that looks generically like the following:

```
System1Controller : IController // from System.Web.Mvc

ISystem1Service {
    IList<System1Type> GetOperation(string something);
}

System1Service : ISystem1Service 
{
    private ISystem1Entities context;
    public System1Service(ISystem1Entities context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
}

ISystem1Entities
{
    IDbSet<System1Type> Operations { get; set; }
}

System1Entities : DbContext, ISystem1Entities
```

Using the Unity Bootstrapper and calling Bootstrapper.Initialize() works with the following BuildUnityContainer() implementation

```
private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
{
    var theContainer = new UnityContainer();
    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebAppConnectionString"];
    if (connectionString == null)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("The ConnectionString is not defined.");
    }

    // register all your components with the container here
    // it is NOT necessary to register your controllers
    theContainer.RegisterType<ISystem1Entities, System1Entities>(
        new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(), 
        new InjectionConstructor(connectionString.ConnectionString));

    theContainer.RegisterType<ISystem1Service, System1Service>();

    var factory = new UnityControllerFactory(theContainer);
    ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(factory);

    return theContainer;
}
```

I want to refactor the bootstrapper so that I can load 'unknown' at compile time assemblies, register the types that are contained in them and allow the web application to reference the controller, services, contexts as needed.

I've looked at the [Unity AutoRegistraion](http://autoregistration.codeplex.com/) project and it appears to be getting me in the neighborhood of the implementation that I want, but I'm not sure how to implement the following idea:

```
BootStrapper.BuildUnityConfiguration
    Initialize Container
    RegisterMyAssemblies()
```

I want the 'RegisterMyAssemblies' process to register a wildcard list of assemblies, then proceed to register the types within each individual assembly.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not try to use the application's main bootstrapper (composition root) to configure these plugin assemblies, since that will be pretty hard to get right. It is hard to get right, because the main program doesn't know which types to register, and by what lifetime those types should be registered.

Instead, let each plugin assembly have it's own bootstrapper method, and pass in the application's container instance onto this plugin bootstrapper.

You can for instance, define an `IBootstrapper` interface in a core assembly and let each plugin assembly implement this interface. For instance:

```
public class System1Bootstrapper : IBootstrapper
{
    void IBootstrapper.Bootstrap(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        var conString = ConfigurationManager
            .ConnectionStrings["WebAppConnectionString"];

        if (conString == null)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(
                    "The ConnectionString is not defined.");
        }

        // register all your components with the container here
        // it is NOT necessary to register your controllers
        container.RegisterType<ISystem1Entities, System1Entities>(
            new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(), 
            new InjectionConstructor(conString.ConnectionString));

        container.RegisterType<ISystem1Service, System1Service>();
    }
}
```

In your application's composition root, you can now simply add this code to register all plugin types:

```
var pluginBootstrappers =
    from Assembly assembly in BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies()
    from type in assembly.GetExportedTypes()
    where typeof(IBootstrapper).IsAssignableFrom(type)
    select (IBootstrapper)Activator.CreateInstance(type);

pluginBootstrappers.ToList().ForEach(b => b.Bootstrap(container));
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  I was able to fit you solution into my architecture very neatly.

Comment: Another option is to let each plugin manage its own container instance. This keeps the sub systems isolated from eachother, but this is only possible when there is little or no interaction between the sub systems.

Answer (score 0):

This is admittedly a plug but take a look at my Unity Automapper on NuGet. It allows you to do exactly this sort of thing - you just provide it with a collection of types or assembly names; it will automagically wire up the dependencies based on interface - concrete mappings. It also operates over internal types so you can do "proper" DIP by having your interfaces public and providers of those interfaces internal.